# bootstrap is not responsive for high-resolution phones

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

My site uses bootstrap 3 to accommodate devices of varying screen sizes. I use bootstrap's *hidden-xs* class to hide my page's unnecessary background image on small devices allowing them to focus on the important input components without having to zoom in. This works fine if you resize the browser window or adjust your monitors resolution. It also works great on low-res phones like the iPhone.

However, since bootstrap uses screen pixel size, this does not work on android phones with high resolutions. The result is, the phone user has to zoom in or work hard to select the appropriate inputs as they appear small on the phone's physically small screen.

Is there an easy fix for this so that users with high-res phones don't get the same look as the desktop users?

Thanks!

Comment: You would probably need to check the device and the resolution in JS and enable-disable whatever class but this is just a guess.

Comment: Have you got the HTML for the page? I'm thinking of two things that might resolve this, just want to check the HTML approach isn't already implemented for you.

Comment: @KarlBrown Can you be more specific? I am just using your standard bootstrap columns:

<div class="hidden-xs" style="height: 60px;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="panel col-sm-4 pad" id="formOuterWrapper">
<!--important stuff here-->
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 hidden-xs"></div>

Comment: You can edit your question to add code if needed - code in comments is basically unreadable.

Comment: You can't use `hidden-xs` with bootstrap 4. You will use `hidden-xs-up` or `hidden-xs-down`. Bootstrap 4 drooped out the bootstrap 3 responsive utility. Check the bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4 Migration. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#responsive-utilities. Also Bootstrap 4 changed `meta viewport`. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />`. Your code not working because of you write wrong `class` name with bootstrap 4.

Comment: @Rahul I am actually using v3 I think, sorry for the misinformation

Comment: If you use bootstrap 3 then @andreas is right. Edit your question. If you use **Bootstrap 3** proper `class` name and `meta` it will work all devices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in the `<head>` section of your HTML document, to scale the document based on the screen width of the device you are using.

[Check MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag) for more information about the viewport meta tag and its usage.

Comment: This looks to be what I'm looking for. Let me push this tag to my dev server and see if works.